# If "wallSize" is in localStorage, store the result in bathroomLength variable. Otherwise, do not change bathroomLength

Tags: javascript

If "wallSize" is in localStorage, store the result in bathroomLength variable. Otherwise, do not change bathroomLength.

```
var bathroomLength = 'initial';
```

What is the proper way of answering this question?

Comment: if else condition???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if (localStorage.wallSize) bathroomLength = localStorage.wallSize;`

Answer (score 0):

First you could check: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage for more detailed reference.

As for your question:

```
var bathroomLength = localStorage.getItem('wallSize') || 'initial';
// if there is no wallSize in localStorage, 
// bathroomLength will be initialized with 'initial' automatically;
```